# URL Masking to different domain without change URL Using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First Of all i want to tell that I am using XAMPP.

I have access to a folder in htdocs folder named mywebsite.

I want to wrote some sort of URL Masking Script in htaccess by which when every i visit localhost/mywebsite/index.php , content shown from another domain withour changing the URL.

I wrote below code yet but not able to do that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.co.in/$1 [P]
```

It showing me

**Server error!**

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

Kindly Clear me, Is it possible or not.

& if yes then how it will be.

Comment: First thing _always_ to do when you experience an error in web programming is to look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply read what _exactly_ the issue is.

Comment: Most likely the proxy module is not loaded in the http server.

Comment: Sir, I also enaled proxy mod

Comment: So then, what _do_ you find in the error log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enabled the http servers proxy module as you confirmed in the comments to the question then you also need to enable the SSL proxy feature it offers. So I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.co.in/$1 [P]
```

If that external resource does not only consist of a single document, but has relative links, then you also need a reverse proxy, otherwise the client will break out of your proxy:

```
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass / https://www.google.co.in/
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.google.co.in/
```

However that is something you cannot do inside dynamic configuration files, you need to place such directives inside the http servers host configuration.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).